# Storyboard loading fails on OS X 10.10, sometimes

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, osx-yosemite

We have an OS X 10.10 app in production that makes use of Storyboards. The project is written entirely in Swift, although I'm not sure how relevant this is to the following issue.

Occasionally, we see a crash like this when trying to load a view controller or window controller from the storyboard:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'There doesn't seem to be a valid compiled storyboard at path ...'`

It only happens rarely, and not even consistently for one user. It might crash once, but work just fine after that.

Has anybody seen something similar? Any ideas where this comes from? Filed a Radar?

Thanks!

Comment: We experienced the same problem with a production app written in Swift that runs sandboxed. Our guess is that is has something to do with too much open file descriptors. If the app runs sandboxed, these limits seems to be a bit tighter compared to non-sandboxed apps. I wasn't able to reproduce this bug yet though.

Comment: You might be onto something here, but we see the same in our retail/non-sandboxed build. So probably not related to sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making a lot of network connections? I had the same error until the answer on this page helped:https://twittercommunity.com/t/too-many-open-files-after-calling-fabric-framework-run/28269

It basically says that the network connections caused the error. If you are making a lot of network connections then make less connections and the error should go away.(I had a loop sending requests that never ended)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the hint. I don't think it's network connections in our case, but we'll look into it.